# Is there a way, with Ruby, to prevent the CPU from going idle without blocking anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails app.  Ruby 2.3  Rails 3.2  The app uses resque which runs jobs asynchronously off a queue.  One job, in particular, makes calls to an external (Ebay) api.  While the api call is being made, the CPU of the ec2 instance doesn't process anything.  Is there a way to prevent the CPU from going idle during the api call?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: @prieber For scaling purposes.  We have a scaling group which is triggered by CPU usage.  This particular job, though, hardly uses the CPU, so the queue gets backed up and the ec2 instances don't scale up

Comment: I'd be looking to fix the problem with the scaling system/queue then.  Making the server do something while it's doing nothing because something else is broken is how you create technical debt that nobody remembers 2 weeks from now. :)

Comment: There is an [entire list of fun stuff your](https://distributedcomputing.info/projects.html) your CPU can do instead of idling. Have fun explaining in X years why your workers spend 90% of their time doing SETI@home :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way, with Ruby, to prevent the CPU from going idle without
> blocking anything?

**Yes absolutely.** In fact its trivial:

```
require 'securerandom'
t = Thread.new do
  loop do
    print SecureRandom.alphanumeric(3)
    sleep 0.00001
  end
end
```

This will just continue printing a Matrix screensaver indefinately without blocking until you call `t.exit`.

But its most likely the wrong answer to the wrong question.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I was thinking of something similar.  The main issue is, of course, how to make sure that the thread terminates when the api call completes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with which is working so far.  I realize this question tends to offend peoples' sensibilities.  But, perhaps with the caveat that this code should never actually be executed, I'd be interested to know of any potential shortcomings:

```
module AppHelpers
  def self.prevent_idle_cpu
    uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
    cache_key = "/prevent_idle_cpu/#{uuid}"
    Rails.cache.write(cache_key, "busy", expires_in: 1.day)
    thread = Thread.new do
      while Rails.cache.read(cache_key).present?
        1_000_000.times { 13 * 13 }
      end
    end
    thread.priority = -1
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      Rails.cache.delete(cache_key)
    end
  end
end

AppHelpers.prevent_idle_cpu do
  api.make_call
end
```